# Is this a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, symlink

I type ls -l and a directory shows up like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root  23 Jan  7 03:44 order_pictures -> /storage/order_pictures
```

Is that a symlink? I am trying to replicate this, so I type

```
ls -s thumbs/ /storage/thumbs/
```

because I need to make sure the thumbs folder points to /storage/thumbs/ but it's not working?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's a symbolic link.

The reason you're unable to create one is you're using the wrong syntax: you're using `ls` instead of `ln`, and also `ln` wants the name of the existing file (or directory) as its first parameter, and the name of the symbolic link to create as the second one.

In your case, the right command would be `ln -s /storage/thumbs thumbs`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a symlink, but you have the arguments to `ln` backwards.

```
ln -s /storage/thumbs thumbs
```

You're also using the wrong command.

Comment: ln -s /storage/thumbs thumbs
ln: creating symbolic link `thumbs/thumbs' to `/storage/thumbs': File exists------ says it already exists, but when I type ls -l, I don't see the symlink?

Comment: @Andrew Fashion: If the thumbs directory already existed then the link will have been created in it. To do what you want you would have to remove the thumbs directory before executing the ln command.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You should make a symlink with `ln -s /storage/thumbs thumbs`. An easy way to remember that the source goes first is that the command still works without the destination: the default is to use the name of the source.